# Disable redirect to install.php

Tags: installation, redirect

For example, i include 'wp-load.php' from external file. but if WP is not installed, then while i access that file, it redirects to '/wp-admin/install.php'. How to disable redirection, even if WP not installed, it doesnt matter to me.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Why is this even an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, One trick seems to be defining a constant:

```
define( 'WP_INSTALLING', 'smth' );
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't produce an error or warning?

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_installing(false);
```

Seems to be the way to go though using the constant is still supported.

Calling the function without params returns actual status, passing *false* disables installing mode.

See docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_installing/